# Google App Engine 302 Found response

Tags: google-app-engine

We have a micro service running on GCloud and to our surprise today a very important callback we expect from a vendor service receives a 302 Found response. Which is not an issue, problem is that vendor is not prepared to adjust their code to follow redirects.

Is their any solution around such cases, some configuration in GCloud we can activate. Funny we don't get 302 when we make calls from local machine and testing environments.

Comment: Not enough info.  What is the URL, and to where does it redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the issue: In our case vendor was using HTTP protocol instead of HTTPS since we have a `secure:always` configuration in app.yaml they where getting 302 which makes sense, since app engine was redirecting to HTTPS.